# SQL Server SELECT in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I'm working with two tables:

- INVENTORY which has fields for CODE (primary key), QTY_AVAILABLE and LOCATION
- INVOICE_HISTORY which has fields for INVOICE_NUM, ITEMCODE (corresponds with CODE above) and QTY_SOLD

I need to generate a report which includes the item's code, number of times the item has been purchased, quantity available in stock and location.

So far, I've been trying this

```
SELECT CODE, SALES, QTY_AVAILABLE, LOCATION
FROM INVENTORY JOIN 
(
SELECT ITEMCODE, SUM(QTY_SOLD) AS SALES,
FROM INVOICE_HISTORY 
GROUP BY ITEMCODE
)
ON (CODE = ITEMCODE))
```

But it isn't working. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT i.CODE, SUM(QTY_SOLD) SALES, i.QTY_AVAILABLE, i.LOCATION
FROM INVENTORY i
    JOIN INVOICE_HISTORY ih ON i.CODE = ih.ITEMCODE
GROUP BY i.CODE, i.QTY_AVAILABLE, i.LOCATION
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
SELECT CODE, SALES, QTY_AVAILABLE, LOCATION
FROM INVENTORY Inv INNER JOIN INVENTORY INVOICE_HISTORY InvHis 
on Inv.CODE = InvHis.ITEMCODE
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to write out that whole sub-select statement in the join as you've got there. What you'll want is to to use aliases for the table names and then you can just select the columns that you want, prefixed with the alias. It will be something like this:

```
SELECT INV.CODE, INV.SALES, INV.QTY_AVAILABLE, INV.LOCATION, HIS.ITEMCODE, HIS.SUM(QUANTITY) AS SALES 
FROM INVENTORY AS INV JOIN INVOICE_HISTORY AS HIS ON INV.CODE = HIS.ITEMCODE
```

The point is that you're giving the INVENTORY table an alias of INV and the INVOICE_HISTORY table an alias of HIS and then you reference both of them in the same select statement.

Hope that helps!